# How do I disable EDNS in systemd-resolved

Tags: 20.04, dns, systemd-resolved

I am experiencing long DNS lookup times (> 5s) due to non-compliant EDNS responses from my DNS server triggering (I think) [this bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11849) in systemd-resolved. I'd like to turn off EDNS in resolved to see if that fixes the problem, however  I have been unable to figure out how to do this.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` and contains the line `options edns0 trust-ad`. I have tried removing the symlink and replacing it with a real file that does not have this "options" line and then restarting resolved, however after doing that I still see the following log message in syslog:

```
Feb 15 09:07:35 charon systemd-resolved[1007519]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 31630.
```

What is the correct way to disable EDNS in resolved on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I did find that launchpad issue when researching this problem. I don't think comment #9 applies in my case though as I don't have resolvconf installed at all, and none of the resolvconf config files mentioned in that comment exist on my system.

Comment: Sorry, about that.  The title of the bug then is wrong.  That is OK though.  Have you tried just replacing the stub with the non-stub?  `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`?